# Question with extracting data from Json using Python

Tags: python, json, line, bots

I am building a bot game for my friends in LINE. I'm a beginning coder. I'm trying to call an object in json which includes a string + integer. I've looked around but nothing seems to fit what I need. What would be the best/simple solution?

My code is amateur, please go easy on me. :P
I'm trying to have Python extract through Json, "Name" + "Stat".
Right now it only extracts "Name" and randomly selects an item. Is there any way to select the item + the stat, display the item and calculate the stat? Thanks.

```
Python 3:
if text == 'FIGHT':
    with open('items.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        armor1 = [v for d in data['armor'] for k,v in d.items() if k == 'name']
        weapon1 = [v for d in data['weapon'] for k,v in d.items() if k == 'name']
        magic1 = [v for d in data['magic'] for k,v in d.items() if k == 'name']
        armor2 = random.choice(armor1)
        weapon2 = random.choice(weapon1)
        magic2 = random.choice(magic1)
        calc = add(int(armor2), int(weapon2), int(magic2))
        line_bot_api.reply_message(
            event.reply_token, 
                TextSendMessage('Armor = ' + (armor2)),
                TextSendMessage('Weapon = ' + (weapon2)),
                TextSendMessage('Magic = ' + (magic2)),
                TextSendMessage('You have a score of ' + str(calc) + '.'),
                TextSendMessage('Waiting for next opponent...')
        )
Json:
"armor": [
{
    "name":"Cardboard armor 10 DEF" ,
    "stats":"10" },
{
    "name":"Plastic armor 20 DEF" ,
    "stats":"20" },
{
    "name":"Rubber armor 30 DEF" ,
    "stats":"30" },
{
    "name":"Metal armor 40 DEF" ,
    "stats":"40" },
{
    "name":"Indestructable armor 50 DEF" ,
    "stats":"50" }
],
```

Comment: `armor1 = data['armor']` ? `[... if k == 'name']` means that you are only getting the name key ...

Comment: `for d in data['armor']:
        print(d['name'], int(d['stats']))`?

Comment: Right. That's the issue. I've been adding things to see if I can get them to work. I was successfully able to display 'name' through the bot and randomly select a "weapon". But now I need to get the "name" with the "stat" to calculate the "stat" for the score.

Comment: I've tried various ways implementing your suggestion davedwards.. unfortunately nothing I've tried works.. The process I need is "armor1" calls for data in "armor" aka "name" + "stats". Then armor2 randomly selects a name + stat.. So.. let's say "Metal Armor 40 DEF" with(in the background) a stat of 40. It then calculates the stat of 40 and pluses it with a weapon and magic. Giving an overall score. Then it prints to the application.. "The armor, weapon, and magic." Giving a score. So the stat is only used in the coding. The strings are used to display what random items that person received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying just about everything.. The solution was:

```
if text == 'FIGHT':
    with open('items.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        armor2 = random.choice(data['armor'])
        weapon2 = random.choice(data['weapon'])
        magic2 = random.choice(data['magic'])
        calc = add(armor2['stats'], weapon2['stats'], magic2['stats'])
        line_bot_api.reply_message(
            event.reply_token, [
                TextSendMessage('Armor = ' + (armor2['name'])),
                TextSendMessage('Weapon = ' + (weapon2['name'])),
                TextSendMessage('Magic = ' + (magic2['name'])),                 
                TextSendMessage('Total = ' + str(calc) + '.')
            ]
        )
```

Thanks to everyone and special thanks to my friend Sae who helped me. :)